# pulseaudio not connected bluetooth device after pulseaudio restart but showing it if bluetooth connects after pulseaudio is running

Tags: ubuntu, pulseaudio, bluetooth

I have a ubuntu 22.04 computer that works with USB soundcard.
I configure some pulseaudio properties of the sinks/sources in default.pa.

Now, I want to change to work with a bluetooth device.
The device works and connects to the computer, but I'm having problems with pulseaudio.

If the bluetooth device connects AFTER pulseaudio is already running, then pulseaudio detects it and shows it in the sinks/sources, but the configuration in default.pa is not applied.
If the bluetooth device is ALREADY connected when pulseaudio starts (or restarts) then pulseaudio does NOT detect it.

executing

```
bluetoothctl connect <bluetooth-device>
```

causes the pulseaudio to detect the bluetooth device, but again the configuration is not applied.

Looking in the journalctl output the only error I've found was:

Sep 13 14:21:57 controlbox-prod pulseaudio[12613]: Could not find org.bluez.BatteryProviderManager1.RegisterBatteryProvider(), is bluetoothd started with experimental features enabled (-E flag)?

Can anybody help me fix this?
I would at least want the pulseaudio to detect a bluetooth device that is connected while pulseaudio is starting so that the configuration in default.pa is applied.

Thanks,
Nadav